# How do I find all integral points inside a triangle efficiently

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given triangle vertices co-ordinates ($x$ , $y$)  ( ranges from $0$ to $10^{9}$).How do I find all integer points inside this triangle efficiently? because if I use scan-line it can take much time.[image]

as shown in image we need to get all blue points.(vertices are also integers in given range) and have to find all such points, if answer is greater than 100 then return any such 100 points

Comment: Does this need to be exact or would approximate result be enough? Should the output be a list of all the coordinates of the integer points (which could contain up to $10^{18}$ elements if I'm not mistaken)?

Comment: I want to know approach to find few say upto 100 if more than 100

Comment: How fast do you need the algorithm to be? I wager that for $ \leq 100$ points it would only take seconds

Comment: as fast and efficient

Comment: It would be nice to know more context, namely: how much time does the scanning algorithm currently take (which language / program you are using as well), and how much time (at most) you need it to take. Maybe your current algorithm can be improved without the need to write a new one.

Comment: scanning takes too much time for worst cases

Comment: How much is too much?

Comment: If you wanted the *number of points* at integer coordinates strictly inside the triangle, then (assuming the vertices are at integers) it will be the area of the triangle  minus half the number on the edges and vertices plus $1$

Answer (score 2):

One other idea besides scan-line:

1. Find a single point inside the triangle, e.g. check the neighbors of the vertices.
2. Use [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) or somthing like this together with a fast triangle-point-test to find sufficiently many other points.

I still think a well-implemented scan-line algorithm would be faster because it does not have to apply the point-test for every point, but only has to find the start and end of a scan-line. This can be done fast if you translate the triangle into a half-space representation, i.e. a point is an inner point if it satisfies

$$a_ix +b_iy <1,\quad i=1,2,3$$

for appropriate $a_i,b_i,i=1,2,3$ which you need to compute only once.

Comment: "only has to find the start and end of a scan-line" - exactly

Comment: @YuriyS Should this say that this is the actual problematic part? I added a sentence for this.

Comment: No, sorry, I meant to say my thoughts were the same. But what you added makes this even better

Comment: scan-line: 1) get Ymax and Y min start from Ymax and  we do scanline algo,but with a very pointed vertex at top, that is inefficient though

Comment: @mahendersingh Why inefficient? If you are not satisfied with the top vertex, then "rotate" the triangle to have the vertex with the largest angle on top. It is unlikely that we will present you a complete algorithm here. We can provide mathematical ideas which you then have to implement. At the moment I have the feeling that you have a wrong understanding of what a scan-line algorithm does. For a start: it does not check all "points" in a line to see whether any of them are in the triangle. We can *calculate* the first point in the triangle, we dont have to search for it.